# Print last pages of a big HTML page with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to generate PDFs from a website.
Some of the website pages are very long and I want to print only the last 5 pages to PDF.
How do I do that?

I tried to print out of range pages in the hope I'll get the last page number in the exception, but it didn't work. Example:

```
await page.pdf({ path: 'last-pages.pdf', printBackground: true, format: 'A4', pageRanges: '500-1000' });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to find solution for this? Even we have similar requirement where we need to print only last page. Currently we generate full PDF and return only last page to client but it is adding to response time.